# how to pass data from controller to view in CI

Tags: codeigniter, view, model, controller

I have controller and view and I have very noob question, how to pass the data to view.

```
    if (is_int($page)){
        $this->load->model("Gamesmodel");
        $query = $this->Gamesmodel->games("all",$page);
        $this->load->view("games", $query);
    }
```

and view

```
<?php
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
 {
    foreach ($query->result as $row)
    {
       echo $query->result->title;
    }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things.

1) You need to pass an array or an object to the view with the variables set as keys (if using an array) or attributes (if using an object). i.e.

```
$view_data['query'] = $this->Gamesmodel->games("all",$page);
$this->load->view("games", $view_data);
```

2) `result` is a method, not an attribute, so you need to call it as such.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
```

3) You need to call the `$row` variable inside of your loop, not the `$query` var you are looping through.

```
echo $row->title;
```

So, now you should have code something like this:

in the controller:

```
if (is_int($page))
{
    $this->load->model("Gamesmodel");

    $view_data['query'] = $this->Gamesmodel->games("all",$page);
    $this->load->view("games", $view_data);
}
```

in the view:

```
<?php
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        echo $row->title;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this technique of passing data from controller to view, but I'm getting a PHP error `Undefined variable: query`. How do you access that parameter inside the view?

Comment: @Pat, it's hard to say without seeing your code. It's probably worth asking as a separate question.

Comment: I actually found out how. If I make a call like `$this->load->view("games", $view_data);` in the controller, then I was able to access the variable `$query`, which was the same as ` $view_data['query']`.